How can I enable autocomplete for HTML while using Heredoc in VS Code?
I'm currently working on a PHP project which involves much HTML being "echo"-ed. As there are many apostrophes in the HTML tags, I'm using Heredoc so I don't have to escape all the apostrophes.
However, it's pretty annoying that this means VS Code doesn't autocomplete my HTML code when typing.
Is there any possibility to re-enable this for HTML while still using Heredoc? Or do I have to use other PHP methods?
Note: I looked at solutions like the VS Code extensions Prettier and PHP Intelephense, but these wouldn't lead me to my desired solution.

I mean being able to use the autocomplete function e.g. writing  and it automatically adding 
